# How to see the operations performed in a Tensorflow pb file?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

More specifically, I want to see the operations performed in the graph inside **'classify_image_graph_def.pb'** which is inside Tensorflow's imagenet Inception model.

Comment: I've gotten this far:
    [x for x in sess.graph.get_operations() if x.type =='Conv2D']
which gives me 94 entries like 'import/mixed_5/tower_1/conv_1/Conv2D'. I can then take that string and do:
   t=sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/mixed_5/tower_1/conv_1/Conv2D:0');foo=sess.run(t)
    figure();[(subplot(ceil(sqrt(foo.shape[-1])),ceil(sqrt(foo.shape[-1])),i+1), imshow(foo[0,:,:,i])) for i in range(foo.shape[-1])]

This gives me images that look like convolution kernels, but this is a far cry from a tool that makes pictures like this: http://cs231n.github.io/assets/cnn/weights.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336648/list-of-tensor-names-in-graph-in-tensorflow/35337827#35337827) - basically you can load it (like in the python image classification example) and then run `get_operations()` on the graph, which gives you a list of operations, each of which have a name and a type attribute. You also could in principle use tensorboard I believe, but for that specific graph I always ran into "too big" errors.

Comment: I'm getting the operation name, input and output. How do I use this so I can recreate parts of the graph again?

Comment: here's example of recreating the graph: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/554