# find the variables name of Tensor flow graph file (pb file)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using a graph file which i doesn't know the name of the variables on this graph model

this files i have :-

- training_model_saved_model.pb
- variables

  - training_model_variables_variables.data-00000-of-00001
  - training_model_variables_variables.index

i started by this code but i can't get the variable names so i can set them

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2
from tensorflow.python.util import compat

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename ='training_model_saved_model.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:

        data = compat.as_bytes(f.read())
        sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
        sm.ParseFromString(data)
        #print(sm)
        if 1 != len(sm.meta_graphs):
                print('More than one graph found. Not sure which to write')
                sys.exit(1)

        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        #graph_def.ParseFromString(sm.meta_graphs[0])
    x,y,z = tf.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def,return_elements=['data/inputs:0',
                                                'output/network_activation:0',
                                                'data/correct_outputs:0'],
                        name='')
LOGDIR='Log_dir'
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

error return is expected

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute_model.py", line 24, in <module>
    'data/correct_outputs:0'],name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 526, in import_graph_def
    'Requested return_element %r not found in graph_def.' % name)
ValueError: Requested return_element 'data/inputs:0' not found in graph_def.
```

any help , thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336648/list-of-tensor-names-in-graph-in-tensorflow

Comment: i have got the input names thanks 
i am fasting an issue in start session , when i load the graph file using
`
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def)
saver.restore(sess,model_filename)
`error : TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got node {