# What are input and output node names in inception v3 with slim library?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I retrained inceptionV3 model on my own data using Tensorflow slim. Below files are generated after training :-

> graph.pbtxt, model.ckpt, model.meta, model.index, checkpoint,
>   events.out.tfevents

I want to freeze the graph files and create a `.pb` file. I don't know what is input node and output node in inception v3. And using Tensorboard is complex for me.

*What are the input/output nodes in inceptionV3?(in slim/nets) OR how can I find the input/output nodes ?*

OS : window 7

Comment: Do you have a .pb file ?

Comment: You can find the input and output name from the .pbtxt file. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535500/5695391)

Comment: @AkashGoyal No I have .pbtxt file

Comment: @BibhuPala Yes I know that using tensorboard but It's so complex

Comment: @BibhuPala Ah Sorry I don't see Link Thanks!

Comment: @ChansuLee
If you dont have a .pb file, where have you stored the trained model weights ?

Comment: @AkashGoyal if I retrain model, I get model.ckpt, graph.pbtxt files. I think weight stored ckpt file.

Comment: @BibhuPala I have no .pb files , have .pbtxt files ..

Comment: @ChansuLee So, do you have a .ckpt file? Can you mention all filenames that are generated in your training

Comment: @AkashGoyal Yes I have .ckpt file

Comment: @AkashGoyal model.ckpt-100000 / checkpoint / events.out.tfevents / graph.pbtxt

Comment: Any .meta, .index, .json file ?

Comment: I have index / meta but no json

Comment: Please update the same in your question also. I am writing answer for you

Comment: @AkashGoyal Should I ask same question ? (new ask question)

Comment: You should mention all the required details in your question. So, edit your question and mention the files that are generated by training. And also mention the steps that you have taken till now for your task. <DONOT create a new question. EDIT this question>

Comment: @AkashGoyal Ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A). If you will make it to bottom of [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). You would find this somewhere(specific to inceptionV3) :

```
input_layer=input
output_layer=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

(B). Another way is to print all tensors of the model and get input/output tensor

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
ckpt_path="model.ckpt"
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=ckpt_path, tensor_name='', all_tensors=True, all_tensor_names=True)
```

(C). If you need to print tensor names of .pb file. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620593/2091339) simple code.

Check what would work for you.

Comment: @ChansuLee Have you got a satisfactory answer or have any doubts?

Comment: Thanks to update my question ! I will try this solution.

Comment: Now I know output node but After freezing, I should do optimize for inference. I got error when i do optimizing. "The following input nodes were not found <'input'>"

Comment: You should first test your freezed model. Then go for optimization. Also it is easy to print the tensors(operations) of a .pb file. So, you can print them and verify input node

Comment: How can i print tensor with .pb file?

Comment: Is the first line in the result of the code the input node?

Comment: It depends on your model structure. Check first few nodes and pick one that works for you

Comment: Thanks for helping me